# How do I render a pixel art game in a modern (scalable, smooth, crisp, hdpi friendly) way with Godot?

Tags: godot, viewport, pixel-art

In modern pixel art games, one will usually find the following features:

- dpi agnostic:  Having an HDPI screen does not mean the game is tiny.
- "large" pixels: Game-pixels are big, made up of multiple screen-pixels.
- "crisp" pixels: Game-pixels don't smoosh.  They are always the same size on the screen.
- smooth camera movement:  The camera still moves in smooth screen-pixel increments.  It doesn't chunk up the way game-pixels do

---

**Here's whate I've tried so far:**

If I make the *viewport to match game-pixels*, it can be scaled up (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsj5SGEUZhU) using advanced settings.  Specifically `Display > Window > window height/width override` and `Rendering > 2D > Snap`.  The issue with this is that camera/screen movement will also snap to the game-pixel size, which looks relatively jerky compared to modern pixel games.  It's not smooth.

Alternatively, if I make *viewport match target window size*, I can use `Display > Window > Stretch > Scale` to make the game look right.  But then Margin Containers end up targeting a screen thats scaled too large.

On top of this, I'm on an HDPI screen and everything is tiny by default.   To make it work on my end, I have viewport settings at 2160 x 1440, but this is a ludicrous default for at pixel art game.  Ideally, I could target a general screen size in mm, and have it figure out how to scale game-pixels to screen-pixels (2x2, 3x3, 4x4, etc) such that the window is roughly in that size range.

I recognize that this is a lot of different questions in one, but none of these things seem to be solvable in a vacuum.  The results are only correct if everything works together.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this tutorial covers most of what you want:  [How to make a silky smooth camera for pixelart games in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxVQsi9wnw8).

The idea is to have a (Sub)Viewport where you render your game world. And this Viewport will actually be larger by one world pixel margin, so you can move the image via code to have a smooth camera.

The Viewport would be in a `ViewportContainer` so you can scale however you want (using a `ViewportTexture` on a `TextureRect` might give more flexibility if the `ViewportContainer` is not quite right)

And as a bonus - optionally - you can have UI outside of the Viewport, so fonts can render with full quality.

---

*No, it cannot target a screen size defined in millimeters. Godot does not have such feature.*